# Trying to change outline colour of dots in UIPageControl in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to change the outline colour of the dots in UIPageControl?

In my code, I have the following:

```
subView.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
subView.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

However, setting the pageIndicatorTintColor to "clearColor" renders the entire dot invisible.  I'm wondering if there is a way to make the dot invisible, yet change the border colour to something else so that the dot is still visible?

Comment: Try creating a CAShapeLayer with the required attributes. i.e Set the fillColor to clearColor() and the stroke color to a color you want.

Comment: @syedfa I don't think this is possible but the duplicate question link I mentioned may help you.